# Access state of namespaced module inside router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I'm having trouble accessing the state of one of my namespaced modules inside my router. I imported my store

```
import store from "../store"
```

and acessing my getters like this works fine

```
let loggedIn = store.getters['auth/isLoggedIn'];
```

but this only gives me back `undefined`:

```
let loggedIn = store.state['auth/user'];
```

How do I access my store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For direct access to store state:

```
let loggedIn = store.state.auth.user;
```